# How works the angular factory with parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I'm reading the angular tutorial **[STEP 13 REST and Custom Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_13)** but not sure if understand correctly.

Here create a Factory to encapsulate the `$http`. The clever part is there is one file `phones/phones.json` with a list of phones, and files with `phones/<phoneId>.json` for the detailed info of each phone.

```
angular.
  module('core.phone').
  factory('Phone', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
        query: {
          method: 'GET',
          params: {phoneId: 'phones'},
          isArray: true
        }
      });
    }
  ]);
```

So when he want get the full list of phones use `Phone.query()` make sense because the factory is call `Phone` and have something inside called `query:` (how is that tag called? method? function? ). And because there isn't anything as parameter I ***guess*** the `phoneId` get the default value of `phones` from the `GET` declaration.

```
angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['Phone',
      function PhoneListController(Phone) {
        this.phones = Phone.query();
        this.orderProp = 'age';
      }
    ]
  });
```

But now the last part don't have idea how works. I understand get the `phone_id` from the `$routeParams`. But how `Phones` factory now have a `get()` function and why need a callback function when `query()` doesn't;

```
angular.
  module('phoneDetail').
  component('phoneDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'phone-detail/phone-detail.template.html',
    controller: ['$routeParams', 'Phone',
      function PhoneDetailController($routeParams, Phone) {
        var self = this;
        self.phone = Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId}, function(phone) {
          self.setImage(phone.images[0]);
        });    
      }
    ]
  });
```

So my three questions are:

- How work the default parameters for `query`
- How Phones have a `get()` and how that work to receive the parameters
- Why `get()` need a callback function when `query()` doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How work the default parameters for query ?

e.g.

```
var Phones =  $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {phoneId:'@myPhoneId'}
```

If I make query  `Phones.query({phoneId:12345});`
then angular will make `HTTP#GET` call with url `phones/12345.json`.
Here angular knows that,it need to take default parameter `phoneId` value
by mapping from object list passed while calling get method of resource.`{phoneId:12345}`.
So,you can specify defualt parameter using `:paramName`.

The parameter name in url and hash map object must be same (In this case `phoneId`)

> How Phones have a get() and how that work to receive the parameters?

A resource object has  the default set of resource actions .It also  have custom actions if you define while creating resource object.
 The default actions:

```
1. get    //call $http#GET method
2. save   //call $http#POST method
3. query  //call $http#GET  method
4. remove //call $http#DELETE method
5. delete //call $http#DELETE method
```

> Why get() need a callback function when query() doesn't?

**you can call `get()` without callback.**

Your resource object (in this case `Phones`) will automatically get populated whenever response is returned. 
you don't need callback.

You can have callback if you need to do some  resource operation(`save/delete..etc`) which need some parameter from previous call.

**`$resorce`not return promise**.
Bu the default method defined on it `return promise of the action` which get resolved on success and rejected on error.

So,you can not have promise chaining.You need callback.

You can get more from [angular#$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: so `query` is a custom or predefine functions? Because in your explanation you have two `GET` methods. I was wondering very weird name. I would choose something like `getPhone()`

Comment: Its pre-defined default  action

Comment: I see now , `get` need a call back because beside set the `phone` details data also want set the image to the first picture from the model?

Comment: in your example when you use `{phoneId:'@myPhoneId'}` what is `@myPhoneId`? A variable? a placeholder where i put my constant?

Comment: `@myPhoneId` it is psuedo placeholder where you going to put the constant value or variable